# Optimizing mysql query to load hourly statistics

Tags: mysql, performance, statistics

**UPDATE:** Adding **KEY `time` (`time`)** to the table improved the speed drastically!

I need to create a JSON object with hourly statistics loaded from a MySQL database. For every hour of the day I need to load all hits. The time gets saved in MySQL as a PHP timestamp in a INT row.

The database looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wp_statistics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

To create the JSON object I use the following PHP code.

```
global $wpdb;

$json = 'data: [';

    for( $i = 0; $i < 24; $i++ ){
        $stime = mktime($i,0,0,$month, $day, $year); // start timestamp
        $etime = mktime($i,59,59,$month, $day, $year); // end timestamp

        $count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT SUM(hits) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."statistics WHERE time BETWEEN ".$stime." AND ".$etime);
        $json.= '["'.$i.'", '.$count.'],';
    }

$json.= '];';
```

This code works fine until the database grows. After a while it takes ages to load the query. How could I improve this to become the same result with a better/faster query?

Comment: Do you have an index on time?

Comment: @Mihai I don't exactly know what you mean but I don't think it has an index. It looks exactly like the code here.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE wp_statistics ADD KEY(time)` Run this to add an index on time

Comment: Added the key. I updated the post again.

Comment: So do you get any speed improvements?

Comment: Yep! great much better! thanks alot!